# Single line: create Dict key or update count in swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, null, key

It seems like there should be a simple way to do this:

```
for each token
   look it up in a dictionary
   if it's there already, increment the value by 1
   else create it and set value to 1
```

I can do this with

```
for token in tokens {
    if let count = myDict[token] {
        myDict[token] = count + 1
    } else {
        myDict[token] = 1
}
```

But it seems like there must be a more elegant, single line way to do this?

Comment: FYI - change `+=` to `+`.

Comment: fixed. thanks rmaddy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator:

```
for token in tokens {
    myDict[token] = myDict[token] ? myDict[token]! + 1 : 1
}
```

Better yet, use nil coalescing:

```
for token in tokens {
    myDict[token] = (myDict[token] ?? 0) + 1
}
```

And to put the whole thing in one line:

```
tokens.forEach { myDict[$0] = (myDict[$0] ?? 0) + 1  }
```

And with Swift 4 (thanks Hamish), it can be a little shorter with:

```
tokens.forEach { myDict[$0, default: 0] += 1 }
```

Comment: In Swift 4, you can say `myDict[token, default: 0] += 1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
tokens.map{ myDict[$0] = (myDict[$0] ?? 0) + 1  }
```

Comment: `map` isn't a good choice since `map` returns a new array (in this case) but that result isn't needed.